# Unable to create New Enum in VBA

Tags: vba

I am creating an Immutable Linked List class in VBA.  It provides `ToArray` and `ToCollection` methods, which I have both verified as working.  However the `Get NewEnum() As IUnknown` property is not working and I don't know why.

```
Public Property Get NewEnum() As IUnknown
Attribute NewEnum.VB_UserMemId = -4

    Set NewEnum = ToCollection.[_NewEnum]

End Property
```

Stepping through the following code with `sequence` as an `SList` with the debugger

```
Public Function Copy(ByVal sequence As Variant) As SList

    Dim made As New SList

    Dim element As Variant
    For Each element In sequence
       Set made = made.Cons(element)
    Next

    Set Copy = made.Reverse

End Function
```

shows the `For Each element In sequence` calling `Get NewEnum` which builds the collection properly and then returns to `Copy` and exits the loop after performing no iterations and no errors.  My only guess is that `NewEnum` is an iterator to a variable that is being destroyed when it exits `Get NewEnum`.
Is that what is happening?

Comment: http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/18457890#18457890

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
Public Property Get NewEnum() As IUnknown
Attribute NewEnum.VB_UserMemId = -4

    Set NewEnum = ToCollection.[_NewEnum]

End Property
```

`ToCollection` is returning a new collection every time it's called; this would probably work:

```
Public Property Get NewEnum() As IUnknown
Attribute NewEnum.VB_UserMemId = -4

    Static internalCollection As Collection
    If internalCollection Is Nothing Then Set internalCollection = ToCollection

    Set NewEnum = internalCollection.[_NewEnum]

End Property
```

...but it's rather ugly. Ideally you'd have some instance-level `encapsulated As Collection` to return the `[_NewEnum]` value from.

Comment: Is the static variable bound to the instance of the List or to the definition of the class? EG if I loop over one list then create another list and attempt to loop over that would I end up looping over the first?

Comment: I've only made it `Static` because you haven't shown the declarations section of your class - my guts are telling me a method-scoped `Static` variable is the same as instance-level, but I could be wrong. Better not have `Static` method-scoped variables, and use a private field at instance level instead.