# Attribute modifiers to alter the behavior of Excel/VBA properties

Tags: vba, class

I created a new People.cls file that contains the following code:

```
VERSION 1.0 CLASS
BEGIN
  MultiUse = -1  'True
END
Attribute VB_Name = “People”
Attribute VB_GlobalNameSpace = False
Attribute VB_Creatable = False
Attribute VB_PredeclaredId = False
Attribute VB_Exposed = False
Option Explicit

Private objPeople As Collection

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set objPeople = New Collection
End Sub
```

However, it does not seem to work when I import the cls file from the VBA editor. Am I doing something wrong?

I want to add a Custom Collection Class to be a a wrapper around the built-in Collection class.

I understand that if one does not attach the Attribute modifiers, the Item property would not be the default property, and you would lose the ability to For Each / Next on the Collection.

Comment: Are you sure about your quotes around `people`?

Answer (score 1):

`Attribute VB_Name = “People”` will result in the IDE failing to name your class because of `“”`. Replace them the regular double quotes `""` and you're good to go.

Answer (score 0):

I build a "general Template" for CollectionWrapper's (*.cls)

```
VERSION 1.0 CLASS
    BEGIN
      MultiUse = -1  'True
    END
    Attribute VB_Name = "CollectionWrapper"
    Attribute VB_GlobalNameSpace = False
    Attribute VB_Creatable = False
    Attribute VB_PredeclaredId = False
    Attribute VB_Exposed = False
    Attribute VB_Description = "Extended Collection"

Option Explicit
Option Base 0
```

{your Public Const}
 
{your Public Variables}

{your Private Const}

```
Private Locals As Locals
Private Type Locals
    Collection As New Collection
End Type
```

{your Private Variables as PrivateTypes}
{your Private Types}

{your Private Variables}

```
Property Get Item(Index) As Variant
Attribute Item.VB_Description = "Default Property"
Attribute Item.VB_UserMemId = 0
SetOrLet Target:=Item, Source:=Locals.Collection(Index)
End Property

Property Get NewEnum() As Variant
Attribute NewEnum.VB_Description = "Enumerator Property"
Attribute NewEnum.VB_UserMemId = -4
Attribute NewEnum.VB_MemberFlags = "40"
' Gets an enumerator that iterates through the List.
' http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/vba/5321/attributes#t=201701130621511275744
' http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26721017/unable-to-create-new-enum-in-vba
' https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa262338(v=vs.60).aspx
Set NewEnum = Locals.Collection.[_NewEnum]
End Property

Property Get ClassName() As String
ClassName = TypeName(Me)
End Property

Private Function SetOrLet(ByRef Target As Variant, Source As Variant) As Variant
If IsObject(Source) Then
    Set Target = Source
    Set SetOrLet = Target
Else
    Let Target = Source
    Let SetOrLet = Target
End If
End Function
```

{your code here}

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please note that code only answers do not fulfill quality standards of SO. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer